# Simple integer arithmetic in C language not working

Tags: c, integer-arithmetic

My goal is to input 3 numbers and output those numbers from greatest to lowest through integer arrays, I can't seem to make it work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int a[3];

    printf("Enter 3 numbers:");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    if (a[0] > a[1] && a[1] > a[2]) {
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
    } else if (a[0] > a[2] && a[2] > a[1]) {
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d", a[0], a[2], a[1]);
    } else if (a[1] > a[0] && a[0] > a[2]) {
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d", a[1], a[0], a[2]);
    } else if (a[1] > a[2] && a[2] > a[0]) {
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d", a[1], a[2], a[0]);
    } else if (a[0] > a[1] && a[1] > a[2]) {
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
    } else {
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d", a[0], a[2], a[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: In what regard does it not work? What input are you providing?

Comment: Can you give us examples of input and the output?

Comment: Note that the first condition is identical to the last one.

Comment: For example, the case `a1 > a2 >a3` is considered twice. Moreover, the case of a possible equality is not considered

Comment: You have the permutations 012 and 021 twice, you missed 201 and 210. Surely there must be a better way to do this...

Comment: You're going way overboard. This is a three-element sorting network. It can be done in three compare-and-swap operations against indexes 1,2, then 0,2, and finally 0,1. That's literally it (assuming you actually want them sorted, and not just sort-reported).

Comment: Can you use the max() function?

Comment: Example of sorting network mentioned prior can be [seen here](https://ideone.com/1zyxh0).